# How to convert Vector to String array in java

Tags: java, vector

How to convert Vector with string to String array in java?

Comment: What different approaches have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try [`Vector.toArray(new String[0])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray-T:A-).

P.S. Is there a reason why you're using `Vector` in preference to `ArrayList`?

Comment: `new String[vector.size()]` will give better performance as the `new String[0]` will be discarded.

Comment: @Dorus: Have you got any actual benchmarks to demonstrate this?

Comment: No, was basing this on the javadoc "If the collection fits in the specified array, it is returned therein. Otherwise, a new array is allocated with the runtime type of the specified array and the size of this collection. " My own benchmark shows new String[0] is faster *shame* *shame*.

Comment: new String[0] is faster when the collection is empty and you have made it a constant (as all empty arrays of a type are basically equal). Otherwise using the actual size() is marginally faster.

Comment: P.S. Is there a reason why you're using Vector in preference to ArrayList? Maybe he didn't have a choice. What, have you never updated or used code that you didn't write?

Answer (score 14):

```
Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
String[] strings = vector.toArray(new String[vector.size()]);
```

Note that it is more efficient to pass a correctly-sized array `new String[vector.size()]` into the method, because in this case the method will use that array. Passing in `new String[0]` results in that array being discarded.

Here's [the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29) excerpt that describes this

> **Parameters:**
>   a - the array into which the elements of this list are to be stored, if it is big enough; otherwise, a new array of the same runtime type is allocated for this purpose.

Comment: I just tried this, looks like new String[0] is somehow faster. Oops :)

Comment: @Dorus - I don't know what you "tried", but what I said remains true - see edited question for javadoc reference

Answer (score 3):

here is the simple example

```
Vector<String> v = new Vector<String>();
String [] s = v.toArray(new String[v.size()]);
```

Answer (score 3):

simplest method would be `String [] myArray = myVector.toArray(new String[0]);`

Answer (score 1):

try this example

```
  Vector token
  String[] criteria = new String[tokenVector.size()];
  tokenVector.toArray(criteria);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Vector.ToArray(T[])](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray%28T%5B%5D%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
vector.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Edit: I just tried it out, `new String[vector.size()]` is slower then `new String[0]`. So ignore what i said before about vector.size(). `String[0]` is also shorter to write anyway.