# How can I convert a vector to an array?

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Vector;

//Write your own version of the x.split()method

public class Splitting {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(mySplit("A/b/c/d/e/f/g/h/i/j/k/l/m/n/o/p/q/t/s/t/u/v/w/x/y/z/", "/"));
    }

    public static String[] mySplit(String x, String y) {
        {
            Vector<String> Final = new Vector<String>();
            String f = null;
            String z = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++) {

                z = (x.substring(x.indexOf(y), x.indexOf(y) + 1));
                f = x.replace(z, "\n");
                Final.add(f);

            }
            String[] Finale = Final.toArray(new String[Final.size()]);

            System.out.println(Finale[0]);

            return Finale;
        }
    }
}
```

This is a coding assignment for High School where I have to write my own `.Split()` method, I have understood how to do it as a String but am having trouble converting the vector to an array if anyone could please help me it would be much appreciated. Also I don't know what would be more convenient an `Arraylist` or a `Vector`?

Comment: This may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500259/how-to-convert-vector-to-string-array-in-java

Comment: You can make you `mySplit` method more readable by renaming your `x` variable to `input` and your `y` variable to `splitter`. Also, avoid using Capitalized variable names in java, e.g. `final`. These are just cosmetic tips that do not change the functionality of your code, but will be important in the future.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") *must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: You are clearly young and new to this site, it's awesome that you're interested in coding. This website is not meant to be used for somebody else to figure out your homework. If you are stuck, ask a question specific to what you are stuck on and provide a simple example if possible. Dumping your homework in a question will get you a lot of frowns most of the time. Also, avoid admitting that it's your homework :)

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `Vector` since it is deprecated. Use `ArrayList` instead of that.

You can use [toArray()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Vector.html#toArray%28%29) method to convert `Vector` to `Array` in if you really want to do so.

Eg:

```
Vector<String> vector= new Vector<>();
String [] s = vector.toArray(new String[vector.size()]);
```

You can try this way too

```
 Vector<String > vector = new Vector<>();
 String[] arr=new String[vector.size()];
 int a=0;
 for(String  i:vector){
     arr[a]=i;
     a++;
 }
```

Comment: -1 It'll convert to `Object[]` not to `String[]`

Comment: Yes, the method must return an array of strings.

Comment: @alfasin yes and so?

Comment: `vector.toArray(new String[vector.size()]);` is much better +1

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a vector of Strings into a String-array like this:

```
    Vector<String> vec = new Vector<>();
    vec.add("A");
    vec.add("b");
    vec.add("C");
    String[] arr = new String[vec.size()];
    vec.copyInto(arr); // that's how you "convert" it
    System.out.println(StringUtils.join(Arrays.asList(arr), ",")); // debug printing
```

That said, I agree with Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera: you shouldn't use Vector - use ArrayList instead (Vector is synchronized which makes it performance heavy).

Comment: But, java.lang does not contain StringUtils.

Comment: @user3754559 you don't want to use that, alfasin use that for print array content.

Comment: @user3754559 true, this line is for debugging purpose only, if you want to use StringUtils you should import `com.sun.deploy.util.StringUtils`.

Comment: BTW, it's pretty simple to implement this `join()` if you don't want to depend on sun libraries.

Answer (score -1):

I used c# code to create custom Split function. Hope you can get an idea on how to do this in java.

```
private static List<string> Split(string x, string y)
    {
        var returnVal = new List<string>();

        int i = 0;
        foreach (char c in x)
        {
            if (c != '/')
                returnVal.Add(c.ToString());
        }

        return returnVal;

    }
```